# (Marshmallow) WiFi takes >30 seconds to turn on

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow

My S7 Edge, running Android 6.0.1, takes quite long -about 35 seconds - from when I turn on the WiFi and until it actually connects to any preferred network . If during this time I go into WiFi settings, the window and the turn-on button seem frozen

On my older Androids, this used to only take up to 5-10 seconds or so.

Can anyone suggest a fix? Many thanks!

Comment: That's how it is now. I have a Moto X with near stock M and it's the same. It's an issue with Android. You could create an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list "here") and see where that takes you.